# Android Studio XML multiple root tags error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been trying to do a TicTacToe tutorial in Android Studio. I keep getting the multiple root tag error at the second `LinearLayout`. They guy in the video does not get the error but I do. I have been trying to find the solution but with no Luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player One: 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:text="Player Two: 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="663dp"
        android:text="reset" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_00"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_01"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_02"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_10"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_11"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_12"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_20"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_21"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_22"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code completely, what is your root layout ?

Comment: I get the error at the LinearLayout tag under another LinearLayout tag

Answer (score 0):

You started your layout as RelativeLayout - and it must end with the same tag. After closing it, you cannot add another LinearLayout or anything else. You closed Relative layout with `/>` too quickly and that's what cause your multiple root view problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout >
    <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <Button />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>    
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button />    
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus where to start and where to end the layouts. Use the following code in your activity.

Notice that `<RelativeLayout />` is different than `<RelativeLayout>....</RelativeLayout>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player One: 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:text="Player Two: 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="663dp"
        android:text="reset" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_00"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_01"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_02"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_10"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_11"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_12"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_20"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_21"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_22"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```